# Ant (1.8+) Task for WebDAV Uploads

Tags: java, ant, webdav

I'm looking for a library that implements WebDAV tasks for Ant 1.8 and later. I only found projects that seem abandoned.
A short pointer in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you run on windows you can try to mount the webdav drive as described here =
[Mapping WebDAV folder as a network drive letter](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html) and then use the copy task for filetransfer.
Code google.com has [antdav](http://code.google.com/p/antdav/) but it provides no downloads, only a wiki with example
and [two classes in the browsable srctree](http://code.google.com/p/antdav/source/browse/#hg/src/org/pm/webdav)

After all search for 'WebDAV java api' with your search engine of trust and use it via
java task in ant or use it to write your own ant task.

Answer (score 0):

Sardine has an ant task.

http://sardine.googlecode.com/

Comment: Hey Jon, have you had success with this? I've installed all the correct libraries, etc and am getting a long wait followed by [sardine]:null. Is there any way to make the logging more verbose?

Comment: Ha ha, sorry. I didn't realize you were the creator. Any ideas on what could be causing my problem? I didn't want to put in a bug report because I'm thinking the more likely cause is user error....

Comment: The best thing to do is to ask on the mailing list. Please post as many details as you can think of.